# Make a Login Activity in Android using my own API

Tags: java, android, api, authentication

I've done an API and now I want to use it with Android. First of all I want to make a login and the access to the MainActivity but I don't know how to use my API to check if the info introduced in the Android Login is correct compared with the one i've stored. How can I access to the information I've stored in a database through my API?

For example, I've a method called getUser in my API which returns an User and it's running in my local tomcat. I'd like to access to this method from Android through the server and get an User and then compare it with the one introduced in the Android Login.

For now I've the following in Login Activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private final static String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private EditText inputUsername;
    private EditText inputPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);


        btnLogin.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mini-profile",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String username = prefs.getString("username", null);
                String password = prefs.getString("password", null);
                if ((username != null) && (password != null)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MiniMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Can you explain me more or less how to do it? Or do you know some interesting site where is explained something like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a decent walkthough but it depends on your server-side stack http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/04/android-login-registration-nodejs-server.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write an AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) every time you want to to access your API, the asyntask has to be called inside onClick, then (as asynctask is async) wait for a response in the onPostExecute method, and inside onPostExecute compare the result of your api call to decide whether call startActivity(intent); or showing a error message (for example). You may also want to show a progress in onPreExecute().

You may find many examples of asyntask in google.